# JTextPane, second word must not go to new line when typing and exceeding width

Tags: jtextpane

I'm using JTextPane because I need to markup text.

When typing into the JtextPane the second word always goes to new line. Then also when making the second word longer (after it went to a new line) the scroll bar appears and the JTextPane resizes. If I start typing in a new row then second word in that line does not go to a new line (as long the second word does not exceed width)

I tried adding a blank string that is very long in the first line and seems to do the trick, but this blank line is not really what I want to have.

Also tried adding it to after the text but it gives more problems

Is there something else that I can do to make the text only go to new line when I press enter? I can do it without a blank string using jtextarea, but then I can't markup text as I type.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane()
{
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()
    {
        return getUI().getPreferredSize(this).width 
            <= getParent().getSize().width;
    }
};
```

We can overite the getScrollableTracksViewportWidth method to have a no wrapping text pane.

Website for more info: [Here](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/)